# Paypal: Is it possible to make parallel payment using stored credit card?

Tags: paypal, credit-card, adaptive-parallel-payment

The REST API only supports transactions from a stored credit card in Vault to a business PayPal account,

What we need is P2P, we need a way to perform transaction between a sender (a stored credit card in a Vault) to receivers (other PayPal accounts),

Just like what the Adaptive Payments API,

Is there a way to achieve that? if not are there any workarounds?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the Vault operation in the REST API, then unfortunately, no, it is not possible to use the stored credit card information in Adaptive Payment. Both operations are from different API family (REST API and Adaptive Payment API), so they are not compatible.

However, in Adaptive Payment, there is Preapproval operation which allows storing payer's payment information to be used in future payment (similar to Vault/ Reference Transaction/Tokenization). Credit card payment can be done through guest checkout feature (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/#guest-payments) but if I am not mistaken, there are limitations.